# TypeError: importPoisson() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estou tentando importar de um arquivo externo alguns dados para poder gerar um gráfico e tal, mas toda vez da esse erro, segue meu código:

Também podem falar erros que vocês acharam no meu código que pode ser melhorado, estou iniciando em python ainda e gostaria de aprender também

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class poisson():

    def __init__(self):
        stopTimes = []
        times = []
        self.stopTime = stopTimes
        self.times = times

    def importPoisson(enterArchive):
        database = open('import/'+enterArchive+'.csv', 'r')

        for count in database:
            count = count.strip()
            stop,time = count.split(',')
            poisson.stopTimes.append(stop)
            poisson.times.append(time)

        return poisson.stopTimes, poisson.times

    def plotGraphic(self):
        plt.title("Poisson")
        plt.step(poisson.times, poisson.stopTimes, label="Paradas de carros")
        plt.legend()
        plt.xlabel("Tempo")
        plt.ylabel("Paradas")
        plt.show()

pos = poisson()

pos.importPoisson("eventEntrance")
pos.plotGraphic()
```

Segue um print dos dados que quero entrar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Falta o parametro `self` no `importPoisson`

Comment: Caramba, percebi agora, obrigado mesmo, mas ta dando outro erro AttributeError: type object 'poisson' has no attribute 'stopTimes', sabe me dizer o que é?

Comment: Isso é porque a classe que você tem não tem esse método. Convem rever com calma o código que tem, e perceber exatamente o que cada coisa faz

Comment: Que estranho, eu fiz a mesma coisa com outro método seguindo os mesmos passos e deu certo, agora realmente não entendi

Comment: ENTENDI, VALEU ISAC, TAVA FALTANDO 1 LETRA KKKKKKK, eu tinha criado o stopTimes e tava chamando so stopTime kkk